# Safari css link not in line

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a problem with Safari. In all browsers in the second row input and link are in the same line except Safari. Any idea why?

HTML

```
<div id="searchWrapper01">
<div id="regulationsSearch">
    <span class="item01">Traži u:</span>
    <select class="item02">
        <option value="0">Naslovu i tekstu</option>
        <option value="1">Naslovu</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="item03" /><a href="/#search" onclick="vent.trigger('loadData:searchRegulationsResults')" class="item04">Traži</a>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/hxg7r/2/)

Comment: No problem at all in safari too, just checked it. Firefox (http://s17.postimg.org/j2g195si7/screenshot_23.jpg) and Safari (http://s17.postimg.org/6zapllhfz/screenshot_24.jpg)

Comment: Not in my case http://s22.postimg.org/b9navrdxd/safari.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there can be a 1px difference between browsers, versions etc etc. This is because you are using margins and floats. Use `display: inline-block` instead in this case.

DEMO [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/hxg7r/4/)

```
#regulationsSearch .item03{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:181px;
    height:24px;
    border:solid 1px #333;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin:5px 5px 0 0;
    outline:none;
}
#regulationsSearch .item04{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:60px;
    height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:26px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    font-size:12px;
}
```